A question related to hazard rate of a distribtuion
Let $v\sim F$ be a non-negative random variable with CDF $F$ and PDF $f$.
Definte the hazard rate function of distribution $F$ as
$$h_F(x)=\frac{f(x)}{1-F(x)}.$$
Let $\phi(v)$ the another random variable such that
$$\phi(v)=v-\frac{1}{h_F(v)}.$$
Denote by $P$ and $p$ the CDF and PDF of $\phi(v)$.
Conjecture: If $h_F(\cdot)$ is non-decreasing, then $h_P(\cdot)=\frac{p(\cdot)}{1-P(\cdot)}$ is also non-decreasing.
Some observation:
Suppose $h_F(\cdot)$ is non-decreasing. Then $\phi(\cdot)$ is also non-decreasing and $\phi^{-1}$ is well-defined. So we have $$P(x)=F(\phi^{-1}(x)).$$
Then we have the hazard rate of distribution $P$ is
$$h_P(x)=\frac{P'(x)}{1-P(x)}=\frac{f(\phi^{-1}(x))[\phi^{-1}]'(x)}{1-F(\phi^{-1}(x))}
=
\frac{f(\phi^{-1}(x))}{1-F(\phi^{-1}(x))}\cdot [\phi^{-1}]'(x)
$$
First we have $\frac{f(\phi^{-1}(x))}{1-F(\phi^{-1}(x))}$ is non-decreasing w.r.t. $x$ since $\phi(\cdot)$ and $\frac{f(\cdot)}{1-F(\cdot)}$ are both non-decreasing. But I could not prove that $[\phi^{-1}]'(x)$ is non-decreasing. I tend to believe that the conjecture is false but I could not find out a counter-example. Note that the conjecture holds if $F$ is uniform or exponential distribution.

It seems that according to the inverse fuction differentiation rule, we have $[\phi^{-1}]'(x)=\frac 1{\phi'}\ge 0$, right?

To save some computation:
$(\phi^{-1})'(x) = \frac{h_F(\phi^{-1}(x))}{2 + \frac{f'(\phi^{-1}(x))}{f(\phi^{-1}(x)) \cdot h_F(\phi^{-1}(x))}}$.
Notice also that the denominator depends on the derivative of your density function $f'(x)$...

@AlexRavsky Yes. But $[\phi^{-1}]'(x)\ge 0$ is not enough to prove $h_P(\cdot)$ is non-decreasing.

Since $\phi(v)=\dfrac1{f(v)}({(vF(v))}'-1)$, $\phi(v)$ is negative for $v$ near $0$, but the definition of the hazard rate seems to require $\phi(v)\geqslant0$.

@Ѕᴀᴀᴅ why the definition of hazard rate require $\phi(v)\ge 0$? The hazard rate is just defined as $\frac{f(v)}{1-F(v)}$.

I would like to note that  $[\phi^{-1}]'$ being decreasing does not implies $h_P(x)$ NOT be increasing.
